# My program returns exited with status 0 on heroku

Tags: python, heroku, flask

I have simply copy pasted the default program from python for heroku;

```
import os
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    return 'Hello World!'

run(host='localhost', port=8080)
```

it returns an error "exited with status 0", which after research i have found out to mean "exitted succesfully". How do i fix this as the website is giving the error ". It returns no other traceback error.

```
An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. Please try again in a few moments.

If you are the application owner, check your logs for details.
```

Comment: What is `run` function, where is it imported?

Comment: im sorry the last line isn't even necessary. Also it gives 503 error. Why is it caused and how do i stop it?

Comment: you have to run your flask server. so you need the last line.

Comment: well the tutorial on heroku doesn't shwo it required

Answer (score 0):

I think you have answered your question in your comment on your own.

On Heroku, Flask applications don't seem to run with the Flask/werkzeug app-runner, but via gunicorn, so go to [the tutorial](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python#declare-process-types-with-procfile), scroll a bit up to see the exact example (without a `run()` line), then look at the invocation via Procfile containing `web: gunicorn hello:app`.

`hello` there refers to your hello.py, and `app` to the variable app inside it.